# snapshot from browser with flash or javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, screenshot

I saw a thread here suggesting using a HPA to take a browser screenshot, but I was wondering if you could help me. I would like to be able to select a part of a piece of a web page and render it as an image. I know flex can take images of its own canvas, but is it possible to take a picture of the rest of the page?

I would like to be able to do it with just flash and javascript, and without a plugin. I realise that I may be asking for magic, so thanks for your help.

Comment: Flash IS provided via a plugin in many browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Flex can do it, then Flash should also be able to do it.

Doing it client side is if nothing else, rather unreliable. Personally I would go for either an external service like http://snapcasa.com/ or if you have access to your server go for a server side solution like http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will try those if I can't get the client side version working.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, for security reasons, it would be impossible for you to take a snapshot of the browser itself.

But, you *should* be able to read the HTML, and then use the Browser component in Flash to display that HTML, then take a screenshot of that. I don't think it'd be as easy as that, but take a look at this post for as a start: [Flex.html](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/html_and_flex_1.html)

Comment: Good idea. I will investigate that and see how it goes. Thank you