# If there a way I can upload a screenshot directly to a web page?

Tags: file-upload, wysiwyg, image-upload

I have a ticketing system and I have a filed for a user to upload a file. However, many time uses want to upload a screenshot they took of their screen. It is very painful to take screenshot make a file out of it they uploaded it.

If there a way I Can have the user page the screen shot directly into my form and then when they submit it gets attached to their post?

I seen this WYSIWYG http://www.tinymce.com/ and you can past a screen shot directly into your post if you purchase their extra ad-on. But I am trying to avoid the purchase also I would like to make a field only for the image so I can control the display size of the image. So if a user is uploaded a screen shot of a screen that is 24" and the viewer is using a 17" monitor it would not looks huge on the screen.

Any ideas? and APIs?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a web WYSIWYG editor a screenshot can be pasted into?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618165/is-there-a-web-wysiwyg-editor-a-screenshot-can-be-pasted-into)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to take a screenshot of your own webpage then [this](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) may help you. This can be done through JS.

Another approach can be Flash based, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462461/snapshot-from-browser-with-flash-or-javascript).

Comment: I am trying to upload a scapshot picture.  if I press the "Print Scrn" button on my keyboard Windows takes a picture of your screen. If I was sending a email from outlook then I can do a paste into outlook and this will past the screen shot into outlook. I am trying to do the same thing in my system so if a user did a "Print Scrn" on their computer I want them to be able to paste this image directly into my site and like it is out look.